# Передача std::string через read\write

Tags: c++

У меня есть класс, объект которого я передаю через сокет посредством `read()` и `write()`. Среди полей класса есть поля стандартных типов (`int` и `char`) и поле типа `std::string`.

Я инициализирую поля класса, поле типа `string` инициализирую строковой константой (возможно это важно). После передачи на сервер я вывожу в терминал значения полей. Все поля выводятся корректно, но когда я вывожу поле типа `string` - возникает ошибка сегментации.

Посему вопрос: как передать тип `string` так, чтобы он корректно выводился?

Comment: Вы что, передаёте и принимаете ссылку/указатель на экземпляр объекта?

Comment: @PinkTux я передаю указатель на объект, а что я принимаю - это скорее вопрос к функции read()

Comment: Так делать нельзя. И даже если в объекте содержатся только generic-типы, то имеет смысл писать отдельные функции для .их приёма и восстановления. И причин тому навалом, начиная с банальной разной архитектуре на клиенте и сервере...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо передать его содержимое как C-строку, а приняв, восстановить `string` из этого значения.

Что-то вроде

```
string s;
...
int l = s.length()+1;
write(&l,sizeof(l));
write(s.c_str(),l);
```

с другой стороны

```
string s;
int l;
read(&l,sizeof(l));
char * buf = new char[l];
read(buf,l);
s = buf;
delete[] buf;
```

Примерно так...

Comment: Вместо `int` лучше использовать типы с фиксированной длиной `<cstdint>`, а то ведь клиент с сервером могут иметь разные размеры для `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Передавать в виде "сырых" данных можно только так называемые POD-типы. Т.е. для которых достаточно копировать `sizeof(T)` байт для получения полной копии объекта. `std::string` к таким типам не относится. Чтобы правильно передать его по сети необходимо преобразовать его в последовательность POD-типов. Например, передать сначала длину строки в байтах `size()`, а потом последовательно все байты `data()`. После чего, на приёмной стороне сформировать новый объект `std::string` из этих данных, используя соответствующий конструктор.

Для получения более подробной информации, ознакомьтесь с таким понятием как "сериализация".